# Custom lib.d.ts in VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and, to some extent as an excerise, I'm trying to write the beginning of a type definition file for some of Adobe's "ExtendScript" APIs, which are based on ECMAScript.

Since the host environment isn't a browser, I have the same problem that the Node.js folk have in dealing with a cluttered namespace due to the still monolithic lib.d.ts file.

So far, it's not too bad. There is a definition for `File` in the global scope in lib.d.ts and the ExtendScript hosting environment also defines a `File` in the global scope. But the collision is minor and I can live with a couple of spurious methods polluting the `File` interface.

I'm still wondering if I could not rather just put a copy of `lib.d.ts` in my project, throw most of it out and tell the compiler to use that.

Is there a way to do that? I can't see any `tsc` compiler option to override the `lib.d.ts`. I also don't see where I would specify any custom compiler options in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `--nolib` flag to the TypeScript compiler to remove the `lib.d.ts` definitions from the compilation...

```
tsc --nolib app.ts
```

This will remove absolutely everything from the global scope, so you will have to define all everything you need to use, which in your case is probably exactly what you want.

Comment: This isn't possible from VS2013 as far as I know

Comment: I think there used to be a configuration element for it: `<TypeScriptIncludeDefaultLib>false</TypeScriptIncludeDefaultLib>` but I have tried this in VS2013.4 and it has no effect. Let me investigate.

Comment: I can find historical evidence of this, but I've had to ask @RyanCavanaugh for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another file, say mylib.d.ts, and put necessary declarations there. TypeScript will merge interface declarations into one. For example:

```
// First.d.ts
export interface IProtocol {
  method1(): string;
}

// Second.d.ts
export interface IProtocol {
  method2(): string;
}
```

Will be merged into a single interface automatically and both methods will be available to IProtocol instances in your app.

You can even have declare method overloads in .d.ts files. The thing you cannot do in standard .ts files.